# On Firefox, overflow: hidden works, but scrollbars and spaces remain

Tags: html, css, firefox

I know Firefox is a bit inconsistent with overflow: hidden; and I read the related stories. So on top of the overflow: hidden; property, I aslo added clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0); and even -moz-overflow: hidden;. In the result, the overflow is indeed hidden, but a large blank space remains where the overflow would have been. How to get rid of this?

Here is my CSS:

```css
    .site-footer {
        position: relative;
        display: table;
        -moz-overflow: hidden;
        overflow: hidden;
        clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
        background-color: #10142F;
        width: 100%;
        padding-top: 30px;
    }

    .site-footer::before{
        content: "";
        width: 350%;
        max-width: 350%;
        display: table-cell;
        height: 120%;
        left: -125%;
        top: -10%;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 0;
        background-image: url('media/backgrounds/blue-planet-4-1700-2.jpg');
        background-size: contain;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        -webkit-animation: spin 160s linear reverse infinite;
        animation: spin 160s linear reverse infinite;
    }
```

The problematic element is the rotating background pseudo-element, which is bigger than the parent element (on purpose), but which I should be able to cut off with css.

Here is the website:
[www.satya-ame-art.com](https://satya-ame-art.com)

This problem occurs at the very end of this website's footer. On Chrome and Safari, it works fine...

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give overflow: hidden to the page element

```
#page {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Deepu, that did the trick! And on top of that, it also solved the strange double scroll-bar problem which I had been trying to wrap my head around.